# Can udev rules create new device properties?

Tags: udev

I wrote a udev rule to create a property in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-backlight-scale.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", \
KERNEL=="amdgpu_bl1", \
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", \
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/amdgpu_bl1", \
ENV{GSD_BACKLIGHT_SCALE}="non-linear"
```

`udevadm test /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1` says that the property should be created.

```
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/amdgpu_bl1
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=backlight
TAGS=:seat:systemd:
CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:systemd:
ID_PATH=pci-0000:03:00.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_03_00_0
ID_FOR_SEAT=backlight-pci-0000_03_00_0
GSD_BACKLIGHT_SCALE=non-linear
SYSTEMD_WANTS=systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl1.service
USEC_INITIALIZED=23289223
Unload kernel module index.
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

But the property doesn't appear in the output of `udevadm info --path=/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1 --query=property` after rebooting.

```
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.0/drm/card1/card1-eDP-1/amdgpu_bl1
SUBSYSTEM=backlight
USEC_INITIALIZED=23289223
NVME_HOST_IFACE=none
ID_PATH=pci-0000:03:00.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_03_00_0
ID_FOR_SEAT=backlight-pci-0000_03_00_0
SYSTEMD_WANTS=systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl1.service
TAGS=:systemd:seat:
CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:seat:
```

Edit: I removed the devpath line entirely, like in [this section in the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#ACPI). Now the rule is

```
ACTION=="add", \
KERNEL=="amdgpu_bl1", \
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", \
ENV{GSD_BACKLIGHT_SCALE}="non-linear"
```

But that still didn't work.

I tried creating another udev rule that writes to a file to see if they're being run at all. `ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="amdgpu_bl1", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo applied > /home/basilmari/udev-debug.log'" "` did work.

So can udev rules create device properties in the first place? I haven't found any resources stating this explicitly.

Comment: Have you done any research already? Where, what did you find, and how was in (un)helpful? https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Do not use DEVPATH or DEVNAME as indentity check, they can change! - at least - as long as you dont know exactly, what you are doing. (no expert)
EDIT: By the way, if you enter `udevadm info /sys[DEVPATH]`, then DEVPATH is listed up under prefix E, which means Environment Variable, shouldnt it be `ENV{DEVPATH}==`

if you run `udevadm test /sys[DEVPATH]` with the actually DEVPATH, the environment property will be shown as assigned, but if you reboot, the DEVPATH can change, and you would get no match, and then the property will not be assigned. Perhaps thats the fact in your case.
if you look at https://www.linux.org/docs/man7/udev.html, you see $devpath, %p in udev rule expands to the actual DEVPATH and $devnode, %N expands to the actual DEVNAME, the kernel or udev sets for the device